# Magento 2.3 Product getSpecialPrice

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i have a function which sets the correct price for calculation:

```
$_product->getSpecialPrice() ? $_product->getSpecialPrice() : $_product->getCustomUnitAmount()*$_product->getPricePerCustomUnit()
```

if we have special price set it should return special price and otherwise normal product price based on calculation.

however special price from and to dates are way in the past and $_product->getSpecialPrice()  returns original price back instead of null / false

is there a correct way to check if product has special price set or not ?

or it's a magento 2 bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code to check if product have special price or not

```
$specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
$specialfromdate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
$specialtodate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
$today = time();

   if ((is_null($specialfromdate) &&is_null($specialtodate)) || ($today >= 
    strtotime($specialfromdate) &&is_null($specialtodate)) || ($today <= 
    strtotime($specialtodate) &&is_null($specialfromdate)) || ($today >= 
    strtotime($specialfromdate) && $today <= strtotime($specialtodate))) {
    $specialPriceExist = true;
   }else{
     $specialPriceExist = false;
   }
```

then you can check like below in your code

```
$specialPriceExist ? $specialPriceExist : $_product->getCustomUnitAmount()*$_product->getPricePerCustomUnit()
```

Comment: thx did exactly that..

Comment: Happy to help, please accept and upvote!!